# How do I change the terminal inside Visual Studio code to use the non-Rosetta one i.e. have it use the arm64 one?

Tags: python, python-2.7, visual-studio-code, arm64, apple-m1

I am new to python and am trying to run a python 2.7 [script](https://github.com/peterfillmore/pyTR31/blob/master/CreateTR31Block.py).
Got pip for python 2.7 and installed a dependency of pyCrypto from the mac terminal shell.

The downloaded python script, I want to try, runs fine in the terminal app when I execute it using python2.

Now I open it in vscode and try to run the script in its terminal and I get

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/xxx/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/_DES3.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /Users/xxx/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/_DES3.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
        /Users/xxx/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/_DES3.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

When I run
`uname -m` inside a vscode terminal(zsh) on an M1 Mac, I see an output of `x86_64`, implying the terminal is running under Rosetta and looking for the intel version of the library.

And when I run `uname -m` in the regular mac terminal app, I see `arm64`

How do I change the terminal inside vscode to use the non rosetta one?
Or how do I get the script to run from within vscode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not familiar with VSCode, but you can manually force the chosen architecture slice of anything you launch with the `arch` command (see `man arch`).

If you have a script that you'd normally launch like:

```
./script.py
```

Then you can force either architecture like so:

```
arch -x86_64 ./script.py
arch -arm64 ./script.py
```

Comment: Thank you Siguza that did the trick. Next I need to figure out how to debug in vscode so that it doesn't throw the same exception.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was happening for me until I reinstalled VSCode (the arm64 version). When I got a new Mac and used the migration tool, it took the Intel version, which ended up causing lots of issues for me. Installing the correct version of VSCode fixed this all for me.

To uninstall VS Code on macOS, open **Finder** and go to **Applications**. Right-click on the Visual Studio Code application and select **Move to Trash**.

Once you've done that you can reinstall it from their website or using `brew install visual-studio-code` (make sure brew is arm64 by checking for it in the output of `brew config`, otherwise you could just run into this issue again).

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues with "forcing" the Universal binary to run under Rosetta 2, so you might have to download the Intel version and install it with a slightly modified name (e.g. `VSCode (Intel)`) so that they can co-exist side-by-side.

This will force the *entire* process tree to run under the emulation, which will take care of all your shells and debugging sessions underneath it to run the same (emulated) way. Please be aware of how that could interfere with pre-existing extensions.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using anaconda for interpreter selection  (cmd+shift+p) and that fixed it for me.