# Why is platform.processor() returning the wrong value when python is run from my editor?

Tags: python, macos, apple-m1

I occasionally like to use python from within [org-mode](https://orgmode.org/) in [emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)?  However, I've recently switched from intel architecture to m1 and this isn't working very well.

The pydantic module imports fine from my system python - but when I try to import it from within by editor python for some reason seems to be picking the wrong architecture.

From within emacs:

```
#+begin_src python :results output
  import sys
  print(sys.executable)
  import pydantic
#+end_src

: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/tom/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pydantic/__init__.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/tom/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pydantic/__init__.cpython-39-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/tom/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pydantic/__init__.cpython-39-darwin.so' (no such file), '/Users/tom/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pydantic/__init__.cpython-39-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))
[ Babel evaluation exited with code 1 ]
```

From a terminal, everything works fine:

```
python3
Python 3.9.6 (default, Mar 10 2023, 20:16:38) 
[Clang 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Could not open PYTHONSTARTUP
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/USER/.pythonrc.py'
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.executable)
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3
>>> import pydantic
>>>
```

(Note that the python executable is the same)

I did some digging and within my editor `platform.processor()` is returning i386 while from a python shell it is returning `arm`, which is confusing.

**Why is the processor wrong from within my editor?**

My suspicion is that it's something to do with some sort of path be it the system path, the library path, or python's path

## Approaches tried

- This question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72308682/mach-o-file-but-is-an-incompatible-architecture-have-x86-64-need-arm64e] seems like it might be relevant?
- `platform` is implemented in python. Looking at the source code is calling `os.uname()` directly and this seems to be lying about the architecture in my editor

```
#+begin_src python :results output
  import os
  print(os.uname())
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: posix.uname_result(sysname='Darwin', nodename='Danielas-MacBook-Air.local', release='22.4.0', version='Darwin Kernel Version 22.4.0: Mon Mar  6 21:00:41 PST 2023; root:xnu-8796.101.5~3/RELEASE_ARM64_T8103', machine='x86_64')
```

`os.uname` appears to be a builtin and I assume that it is implemented in C which makes it difficult to debug... but hoping that the shell `uname` commands works in the same way as `os.uname` it looks like `uname -a` is lying as well.

```
#+begin_src shell :results output
  uname -a 
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: Darwin computer.local 22.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.4.0: Mon Mar  6 21:00:41 PST 2023; root:xnu-8796.101.5~3/RELEASE_ARM64_T8103 x86_64
```

I'm suspicious that some sort of emulation is going on...

Comment: It's not lying, it's likely [Rosetta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_(software)). Is your Terminal running in x86_64 mode?

Comment: Don't forget you can look at your process list in Activity Monitor under the "Kind" column to see if it's "Apple" (ARM) or "Intel" (x86_64). I have a feeling you're running one or more of these under Intel.

Comment: I suspect you're running an Intel Emacs, and everything within that is running in Rosetta. Try updating your Emacs to a native version.

Comment: @tadman Thanks for the help. Ah.. I was looking for `architecture` let me look now. It's odd because emacs isn't in the list returned by `fuser /usr/libexec/rosetta/runtime` as described here (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/416036/tell-if-running-process-is-running-under-rosetta-or-is-m1-native-by-command-line) and activity monitor says emacs is "Apple" but if I start shell within it (eshell) the python process seems to be using i386. I've identified one workaround: create a python venv from within emacs.

Comment: @Barmar Potentially. I was confused because the executable had "arm" in its name `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs-arm64-11` .

Comment: That should be native, so I was wrong there. Something it's using internally is not native, though.

Comment: Yeah... I don't know what though. Calling `(shell-command "uname -a")` is still returning `x86_64`. I don't want to mess around with start-process. I'm looking into whether elisp has a uname function. Although I might declare defeat - use my work around and post of emacs stack exchange.

Comment: Interestingly if I call `python-run` instead it os.uname() of arm... but `platform.processor()` is still different. Declaring default for now....

Comment: Okay I'm declaring defeat for now - going to use a workaround - once I have a little more energy. I've cross posted a [shorter and more general question ](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/77504/emacs-is-not-running-processes-as-arm-process-on-m1-mac-rather-it-seems-to-x86) on the emacs stack exchange.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the terminal inside Visual Studio code to use the non-Rosetta one i.e. have it use the arm64 one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68781379/how-do-i-change-the-terminal-inside-visual-studio-code-to-use-the-non-rosetta-on)

Comment: Ooh... that very much looks like the same problem, I am sort of pleased that it isn't just an emacs problem (though I've phrased it generally).  I wonder if it's the same question because his is about emacs and that is about vscode... as in the long run the fixes might be different. Yeah... I can probably set the emacs shell to use the arch command as described.