# mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64') error in xCode with M1 chip

Tags: swift, xcode, jenkins, x86-64, arm64

I am facing this issue while running my test suite on CI (Jenkins).

In my local xCode the test is builing and running like a charm but when i use Jenkins the test crash because of this error:

"mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')"

I found out that the problem is related to Rosetta:

- On my local Mac the test is working cause I am running it under Rosetta.
- If I disable Rosetta in my local machine I received the same issue as Jenkins.

I am wondering if there is a workaround in order to make the unit test working also on Jenkins

Thank you in advance for the help!

Environment:
MacBookPro with M1 Pro chip
xCode version: 14.2 (14C18)
OS: macOS Monterey 12.6.6

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the terminal inside Visual Studio code to use the non-Rosetta one i.e. have it use the arm64 one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68781379/how-do-i-change-the-terminal-inside-visual-studio-code-to-use-the-non-rosetta-on)